# UITabBarController selected tab bug (?)

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

My application has an UITabBarController with 4 tabs, presented as modal view controller from parent. Application has full support for landscape orientation, so layouts may occur at any time.

There is a very strange bug that I've seen only 5 times for the last month. Somehow after some operations (users can't tell the exact order, but it obviously involves orientation changes) selected tab item stays "landscape" while others get positioned properly.
I can't provide more information because it's a very rear bug.

Edit: it also happens in another application written by another person, so this might be actually an iOS bug.

Screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try implementing the `- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation` on each `UIViewController` in your `UITabBarController` and then set the `@property(nonatomic) NSUInteger selectedIndex` property of the tabBarController after the rotate?

I haven't tried it before but it could work... Something like this:

```
 - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
      [[self tabBarController] setSelectedIndex:[[self tabBarController] selectedIndex]];
 }
```

Comment: I was thinking about forcing layout in viewWillAppear. But I hope somebody already faced the problem and may be has a solution or at least an explanation.

Comment: Seeing as UITabBar inherits UIView you could also try calling [[[self tabBarController] tabBar] layoutSubviews] On the rotate or viewWillAppear then However it's very strange that this is happening... Are you customising the appearance of the tabBar in anyway or subclassing it?

Comment: no, I'm not. The problem also appears to be in another application written by another person.